# JavaScript native Promise() without callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, promise, ecmascript-harmony

Look at this jQuery code:

```
var promise = new Deferred(),
    some;

some = function(promise) {
    // do cool things

    promise.resolve();
};

promise.then(/*  callback cool things   */);

// init everything
some(promise);
```

I am not sure about architecture correctness of such approach, but I used it for long time and it is convenient for me.

In native JavaScript I can not use such approach. Constructor `new Promise()` requires a callback parameter, so I can not pass instance of `Promise` as a parameter.

So my question is: how can I predefine JavaScript native promise, pass it as a parameter to function and the resolve?

Comment: @user2864740 I know it's an old comment, but is that a joke?

Comment: @Mathletics Not at all. It was a serious comment illustrating an invalid (and recently fixed) spelling, with the goal of initiating a correction from the original author.

Comment: @Mathletics Thanks )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The execution flow would be a little different, but basically work the same way:

```
function some(resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}

var promise = new Promise(some);

promise.then(/*  callback cool things   */);
```

Instead of `some` getting passed the promise itself, it gets passed the `resolve` and `reject` functions. So, the dependency is just the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation that would preserve your application flow as-is.

**Do not use this in real life - you'd be missing out on throw safety (thanks to @BenjaminGruenbaum for the hint).**

```
var MyDeferred = function() {
    var _resolve,
        _reject,
        capturedPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            _resolve = resolve;
            _reject  = reject;
        });

    return {
        'resolve' : _resolve,
        'reject'  : _reject,
        'then'    : function() { capturedPromise.then.apply(capturedPromise, arguments); },
        'catch'   : function() { capturedPromise.catch.apply(capturedPromise, arguments); }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Felix answer is more acceptable for me, but anyway thank you for your realization

Comment: Please do not actually do this. There is a reason Deferred objects are bad and the promise constructor is better (throw safety).